# How do Blockchain Explorers lookup wallets? [Balance]

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, full-node, bitcoin-cli, nodes

How do Blockchain Explorers lookup wallet balances? Im trying to make my own explorer. For example Bitcoin-cli does not have a method (function) to lookup a wallets balance. `listtransactions` does not show balance.

Anyone with some know-how, can you link me anything? Im talking about Bitcoin but if you know how for other currencies, let me know please

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for a block explorer to know which addresses belong to the same wallets, in fact no block explorer shows the balance of wallets but only by addresses.

The only way to know which addresses are from the same wallet is having generated that wallet or having it's seed.
Wallets are a client structure that collects all the addresses for which you have the private key needed to spend, in order to make it easier for the user to have the total balance, but from the blockchain standpoint wallets do not exist, there are only addresses and UTXOs.

If one could know which addresses belong to the same wallet, it would not make sense to use different address for each transaction.